# Printing output results to one line in the console

Tags: ruby

Is there an easy way to have the results listed in a single line? For example, 
"The numbers outputted were: 99, 85, 70, 50, 35, 20, -2"

```
def randomMethod()

  rand1 = rand(2)
  if rand1 == 1
    rand2 = rand(1..25)
    puts rand2

  else
    rand2 = 0
    puts rand2

  end
  rand2
end

x = 99

#prints initial x
puts "x = " + "#{x}"

loop do
  x -= randomMethod # decrement x by the value returned by randomMethod
  puts "x = #{x}"

  break if x <= 0
end
```

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `puts` in a loop, it terminates with a newline.  Instead, accumulate the values in an array and join them with commas once the set is complete:

```
x_vals = [99]
x_vals << x_vals.last - randomMethod while x_vals.last > 0
puts "The numbers were: #{x_vals.join(", ")}"
```

While you're at it, you could really tighten up your random method.  I'm changing the name to be more conformant with Ruby norms:

```
def random_method
  outcome = rand(1..25) * rand(2)
  puts outcome
  outcome
end
```

and if you don't actually need to print the value being generated each time you can completely lose the temporary variables:

```
def random_method
  rand(1..25) * rand(2)
end
```